# YouTube API v3 + Jquery: need to list all channel videos details (with Tags) & show which (if any) Playlist each is in

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-data-api

needing to ultimately put all uploaded videos to our channel in a spreadsheet/csv but have not been able to find a way to do that *(for free)*.

so i'm trying to rudimentarily learn **YouTube's API v3** enough to get it all listed on a webpage. from there i can copy/paste in to a text app *(TextWrangler)*, then strip'n'fix'n'format to import in to a spreadsheet app *(Numbers)*.

am successfully getting it all except **2 things...**

1. **Tags** are just showing as "**undefined**";
2. **Playlist** is just showing the main **channelId**.

so, **for TAGS** - it'd be nice to have whatever tags have been added to each upload on one line separated by commas. **any ideas on how to fix this?**

and, **for PLAYLIST** - it'd be great to have whatever playlist(s) each video is in be listed on one line separated by commas. **any ideas on how to fix this?**

*note:* everything i could find regarding playlisted videos show how to do it the other way around... *list each video within a particular playlist*. if i did that, then i would have to do this process multiple times for each playlist; additionally, not all videos are in playlists.

here's the code i'm working with thus far... `codepen.io/syberknight/pen/BQagdQ`

*note:* it is NOT styled except to give each item obvious separation.

*note:* i know HTML/CSS but am just learning Jquery - i'm a noob at best. so please don't give vague & undetailed replies.

much appreciated!

Comment: FYI: new pen @ http://codepen.io/syberknight/pen/pNjZvJ

Comment: i have searched & searched & searched - it would 'seem' as tho nobody has ever posted/blogged/anything on how to retrieve TAGS via Jquery! and all my attempts have failed. additionally, it also would 'seem' as tho one can only list all records of a channel OR playlist & not the other way around to show which playlist(s) a record is in. ugh :-(